# Accessing Spark Tables (Parquet on ADLS) using Presto from a Local Linux Machine

Tags: hive, presto, hive-metastore

Would like to know if we can access the Spark External tables with MS SQL as metastore and external files on Azure Data lake using Hive Metastore service (Presto) from a Linux Machine.

We are trying to access the spark delta tables having parquet files on ADLS through Presto. Below is the scenario. I would like to know if there is a possible way to achieve this. We are doing this as a POC only and we believe knowing the answer will take us to next step.

Our central data repository is all spark Delta tables created by many pipelines. The data is stored in Parquet format. MS SQL is the external metastore. Data in these spark tables are used by other teams/applications and they would like to access these data through Presto.

We learnt that Presto uses the metastore service of Hive to access the hive table details. We tried accessing the tables from Hive (thinking if this works Presto also works). But we find problems with different filesystems. We have setup Hadoop and Hive in one single Linux machine. The versions are 3.1.2 & 3.1.1. The hive service is connecting to the SQL metastore and showing the results of few basic commands. However when it comes to accessing the actual data stored in parquet in a ADLS path, it fails saying File system exception. I understand this problem that it is an interaction of many file systems like (ADFS, HDFS, linux) but not finding any blogs that guides us. Kindly help.

Hive Show Database command:

```
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
OK
7nowrtpocqa
c360
default
digital
```

Hive Listing tables:

```
hive> SHOW TABLES;
OK
amzn_order_details
amzn_order_items
amzn_product_details
```

Query data from Orders table:

```
hive> select * from dlvry_orders limit 3;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "dbfs"
Time taken: 3.37 seconds
```

How can I make my setup access the Datalake files and bring in the data?
I believe my metastore should have the exact full path of the ADLS where files are stored. If it is, how will my Hive/Hadoop in Linux will understand the path.
If it can recognize the path also, in which configuraion file should I give the credentials for accessing the data lake (in any .XML)
How can the different file systems interact

Kindly help. Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: I have using same infra with aws services now. In my case, EMR supports S3 by using EMRFS and no worries about this. I think HD insight have similar features, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store). You might need this with gen2.

Comment: Hi Lamanus, Can you share little more info? You mean this is the only way to do? Because I have created Hadoop/Hive enironment in an independent Linux VM and so I want to bypass HD insight. So If I make the external files Blob mounted in Linux Machine and make changes in Metastore to access the mounted linux path, will it work? Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: HI Bharath, you may wanna try Qubole which provides a common Metastore for Hive, Spark and Presto on Azure cloud.       https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/quick-start-guide/Azure-quick-start-guide/      https://azure.qubole.com

Comment: Normal hive and hadoop cannot use the adls path I guess, because of the filesystem should be defined with extra packages made by storage provider. That is happen exactly in AWS system and so I just expect azure will do, too.

Comment: Yes. Right now, Presto cant understand dbfs:/path. Since our Delta files are created by databricks pipelines and also our ADLS is Gen1, and so we cant access. We will move to Gen2.